# Window.location.href infinite loop

Tags: javascript

When using `window.location.href` I'm running into an infinite loop (even though it is placed inside a function that is only called once during startup).

```
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() { // only called one time once API's are ready
        window.location.href = ("?name=" + new Date().getTime()); //is EPOCH time
```

`window.location.hash` works just fine (but I can't use that) ...

Comment: So every time the page loads, it redirects to itself... How could it possibly have a loop?

Comment: You need to add an if, to see if the window.location.href already includes the name= bit.  If not included, run your window.location.href and have the page redirected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are creating your own loop.

On startup of the page you are calling:

```
window.location.href = ("?name=" + new Date().getTime());
```

Which causes the page to load itself with a new `?name=time` appended on the end.

What you may want to do instead is change the hash part of the URL.  Like so:

```
window.document.location.hash = new Date().getTime();
```

Otherwise you should conditionally call `window.location.href` so that it only executes at certain times, like so:

```
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() { // only called one time once API's are ready
    if (someVariable == "refreshNow") {
          window.location.href = ("?name=" + new Date().getTime()); //is EPOCH time
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd use the hash part of the URL too, because it is appropriate for a timestamp. For things that don't go into the hash part, i'd consider HTML5 "history.push" feature.

Answer (score 0):

If this function is run during startup and there is nothing conditional to stop it from being run, the `window.location.href` portion **will** execute each time, causing the looping you describe.  You need to provide some condition that will stop the loop.